# JMeter not decoding base64 correctly - Results in blank PDF

Tags: java, jmeter, base64, beanshell

In JMeter, I get a base64 encoded PDF in a **Response** that I extract using the RegEx Extractor. That is all working great.

Then I need to decode that base64 encoded document and write it out to a file, which I'm doing with the following in a BeanShell Post Processor:

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

// Set the response variable
String response = vars.get("documentText");

// Remove the carriage return hex code and condense to single string
String encodedFile = response.replace("&#xd;","").replaceAll("[\n]+","");

// Decode the encoded string
vars.put("decodedFile",new String(Base64.decodeBase64(encodedFile)));

// Write out the decoded file
Output = vars.get("decodedFile");
f = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\decodedFile.pdf");
p = new PrintStream(f); 
this.interpreter.setOut(p); 
print(Output);
p.flush();
f.close();
```

My problem is that the file that gets decoded and written out opens as a blank PDF.

In troubleshooting this, I wrote out a file with the encoded string from JMeter and then manually decoded it using [this](https://sourceforge.net/projects/base64decoder/) base64 tool. When I manually decoded the file, it opened as expected.

I then compared the text of the file that was produced by JMeter and the one I decoded with the tool and noticed that the file produced by JMeter included random **?**'s throughout

I am assuming this must be the culprit, however, I do not know what is causing these to show up or how to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JMeter is not decoding Base64 correctly because JMeter cannot decode Base64. If you are using some custom code to do it I would suggest look into this code first.

1. Given you need to do this magic:

   ```
   String encodedFile = response.replace("&#xd;","").replaceAll("[\n]+","");
   ```

   my expectation is that your either your regular expression or server response is shitty
2. Given you use scripting-based post-processor you ain't gonna need this "regex" interim step, you should be able to access parent sampler response from Beanshell PostProcessor via `data` shorthand

So your great script can be optimized into something like:

```
FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(new File("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\decodedFile.pdf"), Base64.decodeBase64(data));
```

As a fallback option you can execute this `decb64.exe` program using [OS Process Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-external-commands-and-programs-locally-and-remotely-jmeter).

Comment: Your expectation regarding the server response being shitty is correct. It contains a multi-line (apporx 7,500 lines) base64 encoded PDF with carriage return hex code at the end of each line, which is why I am doing what I'm doing. Your optimized code works great!!!